# Does AM Broadcast Use Sideband Modulation

Tags: amplitude-modulation

Does AM broadcast radio in the United States use a sideband modulation, or are both sidebands and the carrier present in the signal? Please provide a reference.

Comment: AM includes both sidebands and the carrier by its very definition. Otherwise it would be DSB-SC, SSB etc etc.

Comment: If it wasn't plain vanilla AM, it wouldn't have been possible to mass produce receivers in the first half of the 20th century.

Comment: This isn't a well-formed question. AM uses modulation, and modulation produces sidebands. The second part isn't an alternative, it is a question about what parts of the resulting signal are actually is transmitted.

Comment: When using an AM receiver, if the tuning dial is a little above or below the carrier frequency, the radio still decodes the audio correctly because the carrier frequency is included in the signal. There may be some hiss but everything is the correct pitch. SSB does not include a carrier frequency, so the audio signals are decoded by mixing with the tuner frequency. Any difference between the tuner frequency and the transmitter's carrier frequency, affects the recovered audio frequency -- the recovered audio sounds higher pitched, or lower pitched, or unintelligible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commercial AM stations in the US use AM modulation.  AM modulation carries the signal in sidebands on either side of the carrier.  If you were to suppress the carrier or either sideband, you'd no longer have AM modulation.

Comment: This is what I thought but my signal processing professor says there's only one sideband, for efficient use of the spectrum. I'm just going to use my dad's SDR and take a picture of the spectrum this weekend. That should provide the necessary proof.

Comment: @Big: If your professor said that commercial AM in the US only transmits one sideband, then he's just plain wrong, and you can tell him I said so.  However, more likely, you misinterpreted something he said.

Comment: @VoidStar - schemes using only one sideband definitely exist, and they are more efficient in terms of spectrum as alleged and also in terms of power.  However, they are not used for broadcast in the US though they do receive limited broadcast use elsewhere.  While forms of amplitude modulation, they are not really "AM" in the usual meaning. The primary historic usage of single sideband (SSB) has been in point-to-point links between trained professional operators or radio amateurs.